# Using a custom function inside of dplyr mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a sql table set up via dplyr like this:

```
num                   gameday_link stand b_height     px    pz    type
 1   1 gid_2016_04_05_houmlb_nyamlb_1     R      5-6  0.194 3.225    B
 2   1 gid_2016_04_05_houmlb_nyamlb_1     R      5-6  0.510 1.965    S
 3   1 gid_2016_04_05_houmlb_nyamlb_1     R      5-6 -1.367 2.459    B
```

What I would like to do is add an additional column called correct, which holds the T or F results of a custom function called isCallCorrectV. The parameters of isCallCorrectV are columns in the table.

Here is an example of isCallCorrectV in action:

```
> isCallCorrectV(c(0.0, 2.5), c(2.5, 0), c("S", "B"), c("6-0", "5-0"), c("R", "L"))
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

I tried using this command, but I get an error.

```
dplyr::mutate(noswings, correct = isCallCorrectV(px, pz, type, b_height, stand))
Error in sqliteSendQuery(conn, statement) : 
error in statement: no such function: ISCALLCORRECTV
```

Comment: Provide code for the function and do not that spelling in R is case-sensitive.

Comment: It sounds like you're you're using a SQLite backend? That's not going to work with a custom function written in R. If you look at [dplyr's vignette on databses](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html) you can find a list of the R functions that `dplyr` knows how to convert to SQL (and `isCallCorrect` isn't on that list).

Comment: @42- Added definitions

Comment: The error is from sqliteSendQuery and implies an attempt to call a function named "ISCALLCORRECTV". Still unable to explain this with the material offered.

Comment: @Gregor So if isCallCorrect is made up of only those functions will it work? I assume the alternative is reading the columns into R, performing the function, and then copying them back in?

Comment: @Gregor And yes, I am using a SQLite backend.

Comment: If `isCallCorrect` is made up of only those functions then you could potentially write it out long-form inside `mutate()` to get your desired result. That won't be very friendly, and since your function calls another custom function that calls `ldply` I'm going to say it's not an option here.

Comment: Your two options are (1) (as you say) read the data into R and operate on it there using your custom R functions, or (2) rewrite the custom functions in SQL and define them in your database.

Comment: When you're using a database back-end with `dplyr`, what `dplyr` is doing for you is translating R syntax to SQL syntax. When you start using custom functions `dplyr` just tries to call them. If you're working in R and calling R functions, everything's great. If you're working in SQL and calling SQL functions, everything's great. But `dplyr` can't translate arbitrary R code to SQL, so your custom functions need to match the back-end language (and be defined on the back-end).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Gregor's comments, it isn't possible to use custom functions in dplyr on a sql database. Only the functions define [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html) can be used.

So my options are:

> (1) Read the data into R and operate on it there using your custom R functions, or (2) rewrite the custom functions in SQL and define them in your database

I can use the dplyr collect command to read the data into R.

Comment: broken link , seems exists no more